# Why is summertime in Europe mostly 2 months longer than wintertime?

Tags: european-union

DST (Daylight saving time) start late March walked past to the last weekend of September. But since 1996 we (the Netherlands and the rest of Europe) added a month under pressure from the British and the Irish to synchronize with the summertime in the United Kingdom. DST will run until the last weekend of October.

Now we use a double summer time which means that we are in the winter one hour and in summer two hours ahead of UTC (UTC is almost the same as Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)), because we are basically in the same time zone as Greenwich . However, the UK's summer time is one hour ahead of UTC.

So the question can be asked differently: Why (looks!) do British want to have their summer time another (extra?) month (till october)? Or DST starts there a month later?

I've questioned this also at earth science but they told me it belongs to politics

Comment: I don't think "under pressure" from the UK is quite right, there was a consensus on the need to synchronise the various rules (e.g. France originally followed neither the German/Dutch rule nor the British/Irish one) and a string of EU directives about this. At the end of the day, the current rules do more-or-less match the British practice but the foremost concern was to agree on a common rule. Currently, DST/summer time starts and ends at the exact same time (day but also time of day) everywhere in the EU.

Comment: Summer = tourism = $$$

Comment: @PoloHoleSet that does not compute.  Tourists tend to travel in the summer because the weather tends to be nicer.  Pushing the civil clock ahead earlier or later in the year won't affect that.

Comment: @phoog - Pushing the DST one way or the other greatly impacts what the late afternoon/early evening hours are like.  Morning, 6 to 7 AM, has little impact, but pushing the onset of nightfall back would have a major impact on activities, and money spent on those activities.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet but we're talking about why it's been extended into October from September.  That's neither summer nor tourist season.

Comment: @phoog - That's kind of the point.  I think the idea it that by making it more attractive for activities, one tries to make that time of the year more appealing to tourist and tries to extend that window of time people think of as tourist-friendly.  "Less busy/crowded, airfares are cheaper, still pleasant weather and you can still do activities well into the evening hours while it's still light out. It's tourist season in October!" So, yeah, it's not tourist season, now, which would be exactly why they'd want to do this.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet you don't seem to be paying very close attention.  The end of summer time has been the end of October since 1996 (earlier in the UK and Ireland).  Yet October is not tourist season, even with this having been in place for over two decades.  Official discussions and debates on the question do mention tourism, as well as "leisure activities," but hardly as a major factor in the analysis.  Far more significant are commuting and energy use.

Comment: @phoog - No, I have been paying attention.  I'm talking about what some of the reasoning may have been behind such a move.  The fact that it hasn't borne the hoped-for fruit does not mean that it didn't play into the thinking, at that time. If someone asks "why did the USA go into massive debt to invade and occupy Iraq," I might say "They felt that Iraq oil would basically pay for the whole operation and it would be over."  If you were to respond "yeah, but that didn't happen" it wouldn't change the fact that it was still a reason, at the time.

Comment: http://ec.europa.eu/transport/facts-fundings/studies/doc/2014-09-19-the-application-of-summertime-in-europe.pdf  "They were introduced for the purposes of energy savings and **increased time for leisure activities (through having longer daylight hours in the evening**)" - the report refers to DST as "summertime."

Comment: @PoloHoleSet That report is about whether to have summer time *at all.*  Any statements about benefits to tourism should be assumed to apply primarily to the high season: July and August.  So yes, summer time may have a significant beneficial impact on tourism during those months.  October, not so much.  But even if it does enhance tourism in October, the tourism sector is so dormant in October that the effect will be insignificant.  October is dreary and rainy in most of Europe.  People don't want to hang around there then, regardless of whether the sun sets at 5 or at 6.

Comment: @phoog - no, it's not about whether or not to have it, it talks about impacts, and talks about the synchronization. I didn't cite it as "October vs September," but to point out that, yes, the increased "summertime" and hoped-for impacts were a reason for it, at all. If it's a benefit into late September, there are likely going to be those who feel that later means increasing that benefit. Again, you are assessing whether it you think it's a great idea and seem to think I'm agreeing that it is.  I'm not talking about whether I agree with it, I'm talking about why someone might have proposed it.

Comment: I'm not looking at all at "should it be longer?" I don't think the question asks that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63798/discussion-between-phoog-and-poloholeset).

Answer (score 5):

Why do the British want to have their summer time another month (till october)?  So that Scotland and northern England has daylight at a reasonable time in the morning in October, and because the UK wants to retain a single time zone.

On the 22nd of October 2017, in Aberdeen, the sun will rise at 07:57 BST and set at 17:47.  This allows most people to travel to and from work/school etc. in daylight.  Most people working outdoors will be working during the hours of daylight.  If the clock change were to take place in September, during October there would be an hour of daylight while most people were asleep, and commuters would be travelling home in the dark.  Of course, Cornwall has noticably longer hours of daylight, but no UK politician would suggest dividing the country into two time zones